# trying to click a button on a webpage using vba

Tags: html, excel, vba

I'm trying to click a button on a webpage using the following code. For some reason my code skips to the end after the "For Each" line. Any suggestions would be Great! here is a snippet of my code:

```
Dim htmldoc As MSHTML.IHTMLDocument 'Document object
Dim htmlColl As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim htmlInput As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement

With ie
            Set htmldoc = .document
            Set htmlColl = htmldoc.getElementsByTagName("a")
            Do While htmldoc.readyState <> "complete": DoEvents: Loop
            For Each htmlInput In htmlColl  **'it skips to End With after this line**
                If Trim(htmlInput.ID) = "b2" Then
                    htmlInput.Click
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next htmlInput 
End With **'this is where it skips to**
```

html:

```
<TD id=b2><A onclick="selectButton( 'b2' );"
onmouseover="window.status='Transoffering'; return true"
onmouseout="window.status='View Transmission Offerings';return true"
 class=button 
 href="/cgi-bin/webplus.dll?script=/woa/woa-transoffering-summary.wml"
 target=content>Offerings</A><TD>
```

Comment: Would help to post the HTML for the element you're trying to click.  In any case `htmldoc.getElementById("b2").Click` could replace that whole loop.

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you for the response. I tried "htmldoc.getElementById("b2").Click" but get error '91' object variable or with block variable not set. here is the html:   <A onclick="selectButton( 'b2' );" onmouseover="window.status='Transoffering'; return true" onmouseout="window.status='View Transmission Offerings';return true" class=button href="/cgi-bin/webplus.dll?script=/woa/woa-transoffering-summary.wml" target=content>Offerings</A>

Comment: sorry i'm new to this, see my edited original post for a more readable html..

Answer (score 1):

The id belongs to the `td`, not the `a`, but you can use it to get to the link:

Edit: expanded a bit for clarity/debugging

```
Dim el
Set el = htmldoc.getElementById("b2")
If el Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print "id='b2' not found!"
Else
    el.getElementsByTagName("a")(0).Click
End If
```

Edit2: if using frames

```
Set el = htmldoc.frames("frameNameHere").document.getElementById("b2")
```

Comment: hmm, i tried both "td" and "a" but am getting the same error.. "object variable not set". In addition, I set htmldoc = .document. Any further suggestion? thanks again

Comment: thanks, its coming back as nothing! any ideas why that might be?

Comment: Put a break on the `Set el...` line and wait a few seconds before continuing, to make sure the page is fully-loaded.  Is it still Nothing?

Comment: yep, still nothing

Comment: Not much more i can suggest - that result doesn't match your posted HTML.

Comment: ok thanks for looking at it Tim! I'll keep playing around with it.

Comment: I think I discovered why the id is coming back as nothing. The webpage has frames and I think I need identify which frame to use in my code. This is a new concept to me. Would you have any tips on how I find the name of the frame in html and use it in my vba code?

Comment: You have to look at the HTML source for the page.  Your browser's Develop Tools (typically F12) should help. Then use something like `htmldoc.frames("frameNameHere").document.getElementById("b2")`